# tabs.executeScript: Cannot access contents of url

Tags: google-chrome-extension, tabs

Well, this code **was working** and now, not anymore, WHY? I'm just trying to inject code via content script. (base code)

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "background.js"
    ],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
    "js": [
      "bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    ]
  }],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "19": "icon_19.png"
    }
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
    file: "content_script.js"
  });
});
```

I can suppose it's a permission bug. But, what should I add for this work ?

Comment: How do you know it was working?  How do you know it isn't currently?  What changed in between?

Comment: Because now, I do have the error : Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.executeScript: Cannot access contents of url "URL". Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.

Comment: Are you sure it's not one of the unscriptable URLs, like `chrome:` URLs or Chrome Web Store? Does anything change if you make the background page persistent?

Comment: Also, for the record, polluting every tab with `jquery.min.js` makes little sense; inject it only when needed.

Comment: Actually, I've got the same error with "Page Redder" sample chrome extension for example. Maybe it's not related to code?

Answer (score -2):

You have to add to your permissions the url of the page wich you want to inject your code.

If I well understand, you want to inject the code in the active tab, so you can use the `activeTab` permission that temporally give permission to your extension for the curent tab when the user *invokes* your extension (by clicking the browser action for example). You can read more about it [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab).

Comment: Downvoting, as this code is _exactly_ how `activeTab` is supposed to work.